# Dictionary is being sorted automatically

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to randomize an array of strings to be used in a dictionary. However when I add them to a dictionary using a for-in loop by the end of the loop it has sorted all the values.
This is obviously the opposite of what I want as the whole purpose is to randomize the values.

```
import GameplayKit

let stage01Array = ["Level_01", "Level_06", "Level_11", "Level_16", "Level_21"]
let shuffledStage01 = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: stage01Array)
var saveStage01Dict = [String: Bool]()

for level in shuffledStage01 {

    saveStage01Dict[level as! String] = Bool(true)
    print(saveStage01Dict)
}
```

Here are some examples of what is being produced.

### Example 1

```
["Level_06": true]
["Level_06": true, "Level_16": true]
["Level_06": true, "Level_16": true, "Level_01": true]
["Level_01": true, "Level_06": true, "Level_16": true, "Level_11": true]
["Level_01": true, "Level_21": true, "Level_06": true, "Level_16": true, "Level_11": true]
```

### Example 2

```
["Level_21": true]
["Level_06": true, "Level_21": true]
["Level_06": true, "Level_01": true, "Level_21": true]
["Level_01": true, "Level_21": true, "Level_06": true, "Level_16": true]
["Level_01": true, "Level_21": true, "Level_06": true, "Level_16": true, "Level_11": true]
```

### Example 3

```
["Level_21": true]
["Level_21": true, "Level_11": true]
["Level_06": true, "Level_21": true, "Level_11": true]
["Level_21": true, "Level_06": true, "Level_16": true, "Level_11": true]
["Level_01": true, "Level_21": true, "Level_06": true, "Level_16": true, "Level_11": true]
```

As you can see it starts of adding the values randomly but by the end the they are all sorted exactly the same. Please can someone explain?

Comment: The order of key/value pairs in a dictionary is *unspecified.*

Comment: ["Dictionaries are unordered collections of key-value associations."](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

Comment: Of course... how did I forget this. Thanks